# Time Delay In Twisted Factories

Tags: python, twisted

I have no idea how to use something like `twisted.internet.loopingCall()` in `twisted.internet.ClientFactory`

I need to write python script that scans directory for incoming files with phone numbers, reads them, and makes call using YATE `yaypm` python module that uses `twisted` library.

```
client_factory = yaypm.TCPDispatcherFactory(start_client)
reactor.connectTCP(host, port, client_factory)
reactor.run()
```

Where `yaypm.TCPDispatcherFactory` derived from `twisted.internet.ClientFactory` and `start_client` is the function that will be executed after successfull connection.

If `start_client` only makes demonstration call:

```
def start_client(client_yate):
    d = dialer(client_yate)
    d.call(caller, target)
```

Everything is OK.

(`dialer` is the object that implements `yaypm.flow` logic, full description placed in http://docs.yate.ro/wiki/YAYPM:Bridge_and_then_unbridge)

I need to write something like this in `start_client`

```
d = dialer(client_yate)
files = os.listdir(input_directory)
for filename in files:
    <read caller and target numbers from file>
    d.call(caller, target)
    time.sleep(interval)
```

I know that using sleep function in the main thread leads to deadlock. 
How should I implement the algorithm above?

Comment: I see your answer, @Blender, please tell me how to apply your code to `twisted.internet.ClientFactory` because YATE uses it. Are there any differences if I call `reactor.connectTCP()`?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`twisted.internet.task.deferLater`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.deferLater.html) behaves like a `sleep()` call if you use it with the `inlineCallbacks` decorator. Here is a simplified example that uses `ClientFactory`:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, task
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ClientFactory


class DoNothing(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, connection_callback):
        self.connection_callback = connection_callback

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.connection_callback()
        return


class ConnectionClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    def __init__(self, connection_callback):
        self.connection_callback = connection_callback

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return DoNothing(self.connection_callback)



def sleep(delay):
    # Returns a deferred that calls do-nothing function
    # after `delay` seconds
    return task.deferLater(reactor, delay, lambda: None)


@inlineCallbacks
def repeat_forever(message):
    while True:
        print(message)
        yield sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    repeat_forever('running')

    factory = ConnectionClientFactory(lambda: repeat_forever('connected'))
    reactor.connectTCP('example.com', 80, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

The above code is essentially what your library does with the callback you pass in. As you can see, the call to `repeat_forever('running')` runs concurrently to the one called after the client connects.

Comment: Pretty nice, @Blender, I almost implemented your answer, but have a little question: `repeat_forever` have parameter, `message`, but if we calls callback after succesful `connectionMade`, it calls with no parameters. I catched that it was tricky lambda, but how should I modify it to use `self` parameter? For example:
        `def connectionMade(self):`
            `self.connection_callback( **self** )`
            `return`

Comment: @YuriPrime: I don't think you can without subclassing `TCPDispatcherFactory` and overloading the `buildProtocol` method in whatever protocol is created to pass in `self`.

Comment: of course, @Blender, I already overloaded `buildProtocol` in my `ConnectionTCPDispatcherFactory` derived from `TCPDispatcherFactory`, and stuck trying to pass `self` to `dialer()` (see OP). Now I see that I can simply create instance using `dialer(factory.protocol)`. Thanks!